# If you connect the mkmf library to the rails, then some uploaded files break

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```rb
require 'mkmf'
class BashTest
  def example_ruby_path
    find_executable 'ruby'
  end
end
```

If so, connect the library 'mkmf'.
Then rails can sometimes raise such an exception:

```
ActionView::Template::Error: not opened for reading
```

Or other random exceptions. Basically, this happened on ruby 2.7 and 6 rails. This happens less often on 3.1.2 and 7 rails.

lib: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/lib/mkmf.rb

docs: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/mkmf/rdoc/MakeMakefile.html

In principle, I understand that, in theory, this connection changes the connections of c files, but is the standard connection of c files so different, and why does this happen globally in the entire project when I connect this library in only one file?

Comment: `mkmf` has a very specific purpose, is full of global state and core classes monkey-patching - adding it as an app dependency looks like shooting one's own leg (unless the app purpose has something to do with building makefiles). Do you require all that evil magic just to have `find_executable 'ruby'` at hand?

Comment: Yes, I would like not to reinvent the wheel. But I used another way. `ENV['PATH'].split(File::PATH_SEPARATOR)...`

Comment: Why not just `which ruby` (backticked)?

Comment: Because this is an example, and I needed to search for path for different binary files, on slightly different linux systems in automatic mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because this library overwrites some global variables. If you need to search for a file, a binary file, you can try to implement it using code (only linux based os):

```rb
class FindBinary
  class << self
    def path(binary)
      ENV['PATH'].split(File::PATH_SEPARATOR).each do |path|
        binary_path = File.join(path, binary)
        return binary_path if File.executable?(binary_path) && !File.directory?(binary_path)
      end
      nil
    end
  end
end
```

Or other workarounds.